# Migration error using Globalize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

Some years ago (2013) I wrote a migration to globalize one of the fields of my model using Globalize 0.3.0, Rails 3.2.21, Ruby 2.1.6:

```
class CreateMyModelTranslationTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :my_model do |t|
      t.remove  :name
    end
    MyModel.create_translation_table! name: :string
  end

  def down
    change_table :my_model do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
    MyModel.drop_translation_table! 
  end
end
```

And I added its corresponding translation attribute:

```
translates :name, required: true
```

Now I want to add a second globalized attribute named `title`, so I added this line to MyModel:

```
translates :title
```

Even before writing the second migration script, I drop my database and execute all migrations.

```
bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

I notice the migration script I wrote in 2013 is failing. How is this possible? This is what I know up to now.

The method `create_translation_table!` in my 2013 migration script is adding to the translation table all the translatable fields found in the model, that is, both `:name` and `:title`. IMHO, this is a bit strange because this code is in fact performing database changes that may have been added to the model after the creation of the migration.

Globalize gem tries to guess the type of `:title` and it seems to fail, because I am getting this error while executing the 2013 migration script:

`Bad field type for field :title (nil), should be :string or :text`

I am looking for a way to achieve any of these options:

- Prevent Globalize from creating a column for `:title` when running 2013 migration script, and create a 2015 migration script to add this column no te translation table (I think this option is better)
- Find out how to specify in the model that `:title` is a string (I have already tried `translates :title, :string` and does not seem to work).

Comment: I won't put this as an answer since it doesn't actually answer your question, but in general, you shouldn't need to re-migrate your database from scratch. Your schema.rb (or structure.sql) file is largely there so you can avoid having to re-run migrations once they've already applied to your schema. And most production Rails databases will eventually fall out of sync with their migrations; some best practices even recommend deleting old migrations as your application ages.

Comment: @RobertNubel, links would be great.

Comment: @benjamin the [canonical Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you) explains it succinctly: "There is no need (and it is error prone) to deploy a new instance of an app by replaying the entire migration history. It is much simpler and faster to just load into the database a description of the current schema."

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem before and one of the solutions a found was to always specify the translated attributes in the migration:

```
def up
  MyModel.translated_attribute_names = [:name]
  MyModel.create_translation_table! name: :string
end
```

It was also suggested to avoid the globalize generators altogether and to create the translations tables manually:

```
create_table :my_model_translations do |t|
  t.references :my_model
  t.string :locale
  t.string :name
end
```